# "Page Not Found" when click privilege link from editing tag in Area 51 meta

Tags: bug, area-51, privileges

In Area 51 discussion when editing any tag, if the user doesn't have enough reputation to edit the tag, the following warning box appears:

> You do not yet have [tag wiki edit privileges](https://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

In the warning, the link is pointing to [`https://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user`](https://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), it throws a "Page Not Found" error.

But it should point to [`https://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user`](https://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user). So the extra `/help` needs to be removed from the URL.

I tried to edit the [technology](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/74) tag and am seeing the below screen:

[image]